# Irreducible Factorization of $x^4 - 1$ over $\mathbb{F_3}$.

Tags: field-theory

In class, we showed that

$$x^4 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2 + 1)$$

over $\mathbb{F_3}$ is a factorization of irreducible polynomials, but it was also an exercise to show that

$$x^4 - 1 = (x-1)(x-2)(x^2 + 1)$$

over the same field. I don't get it. Are those two factorizations the same?

Comment: $-2=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$ because $1+2=0$. More important is probably to show that $x^2+1$ is still irreducible. You can show that by proving that it has no roots: $0^2+1=1$, $1^2+1=2$, and $2^2+1=2$.

Comment: It is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_3[i] \approx \mathbb{F}_9.$

Comment: So in the same kind of sense, $-1 = 2$ in $\mathbb{F_3}$ since $1 + 2 = 0$?

Comment: @Julian Yes, that is the definition of $-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because $+2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$.